# Helm requirements.yaml condition scopes in umbrella charts

Tags: kubernetes, charts, kubernetes-helm

I have separate **zookeeper** chart. I also have separate **kafka** chart. There is dependency to zookeeper chart in requirements.yaml of kafka chart with condition zookeeper.enabled. By default in values.yaml of kafka chart

```
zookeeper:
  enabled: true
```

Meaning kafka chart at build time includes both kafka and zookeeper charts, at runtime zookeeper will be deployed in accordance with the above mentioned condition.

Now I want to have some new umbrella chart, let's call it **TLC chart**. In requirements I put dependency on zookeeper chart as well as on kafka chart. Moreover I defining in values.yaml of TLC below

```
kafka:
  zookeeper:
    enabled: false
```

in order to disable kafka internal zookeeper deployment. I am expecting when I deploy my TLC I will get kafka and zookeeper, however receiving error that zookeeper service exists. It happens because it tries to deploy internal kafka zookeeper as well as zookeeper that defined in requirements of TLC.

So my question is why condition on zookeeper.enabled didn't work, I override it from TLC so I expecting it will not deploy internal zookeeper.

Comment: Can you include your requirements.yaml, or the relevant parts from it in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, fixed the issue.

I added to kafka chart requirements.yaml, below condition

```
dependencies:
  - name: zookeeper
    version: ...
    repository: ...
    condition: kafka.zookeeper.enabled,zookeeper.enabled
```

instead of

```
dependencies:
  - name: zookeeper
    version: ...
    repository: ...
    condition: zookeeper.enabled
```

This way I can be sure that when kafka chart will act as a subchart for TLC, internal zookeeper can be disabled because of **kafka.zookeeper.enabled** condition.